# Focus/Scroll to a sibling <p> of a link when clicking the link

Tags: angularjs, focus, offset, scrolltop

I'm facing a problem scrolling/focusing a scrollable *div* inside a *table* to a *p* which is the previous sibling of the link being clicked

I tried with the *focus()* and it isn't scrolling, only changes the focus and I need to scroll to the previous *p* on the click.

Here is the template.jade of the *p* s

```
td
  p.focusedAfterClick(tabindex="-1") Text I want to scroll to
  p.link(ng-click='focus($event)') Some random text
```

Here is the function js

```
focusAfterClick = function($event) {
 var link = el.find($event.target).first();
 var prev = link.prev();
 prev.focus();
};
```

I tried with the animation scrollTop method passing the offset().top from the prev

but the scroll behaviour is not what I'm looking for because it scrolls more than it should...

I hope someone faced with the same problem before and got an idea to fix it, because I've looked for a solution everywhere and didnt find it...

Thank you for the time (: